# How to extend Lucene's StandardAnalyzer for custom special character treatment?

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using Lucene's StandardAnalyzer for a specific index property.
As special characters like `àéèäöü` do not get indexed as expected, I want to replace these characters:

- à -> a
- é -> e
- è -> e
- ä -> ae
- ö -> oe
- ü -> ue

What is the best approach to extend the `org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer`class?

I was looking for a way where the standard parser iterates over all tokens (words) and I can retrieve word by word and do the magic there.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: It would be easier to help you out if you showed what all methods are you calling from `StandardAnalyzer`. (FYI you can't extend it since the class is final). That said, it looks like `StandardAnalyzer` has a constructor that takes a `Reader`. You could probably take advantage of this and pass it a custom reader?

Answer (score 3):

I would propose to use `MappingCharFilter`, that will allow to have a map of Strings that will be replaces by Strings, so it will fit your requirements perfectly.

Some additional info - https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/charfilter/MappingCharFilter.html

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't *extend* `StandardAnalyzer`, since analyzer implementations are final. The meat of an analyzer implementation is the `createComponents` method, and you would have to override that anyway, so you wouldn't get much from extending it anyway.

Instead, you can copy the StandardAnalyzer source, and modify the `createComponents` method. For what you are asking for, I recommend adding [`ASCIIFoldingFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/ASCIIFoldingFilter.html), which will attempt to convert UTF characters (such as accented letters) into ASCII equivalents. So you could create an analyzer something like this:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
  @Override
  protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(final String fieldName) {
    final StandardTokenizer src = new StandardTokenizer();
    src.setMaxTokenLength(maxTokenLength);
    TokenStream tok = new StandardFilter(src);
    tok = new LowerCaseFilter(tok);
    tok = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(tok); /*Adding it before the StopFilter would probably be most helpful.*/
    tok = new StopFilter(tok, StandardAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(src, tok) {
      @Override
      protected void setReader(final Reader reader) {
        src.setMaxTokenLength(StandardAnalyzer.DEFAULT_MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH);
        super.setReader(reader);
      }
    };
  }

  @Override
  protected TokenStream normalize(String fieldName, TokenStream in) {
    TokenStream result = new StandardFilter(in);
    result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
    tok = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(tok);
    return result;
  }
}
```